# how to implement ltr / rtl in nuxtjs

Tags: nuxt.js

i'm working on a multilingual site where i need to implement ltr/rtl too. i didn't bother with nuxt-i18n. instead i'm reading from a json file where my languages and translations are, and use vuex to store language and use it. this part is ok and i can change and read on my components.
the problem is with direction. i'm using vutify 2 and not gonna use tailwind so one option out! i know vutify has rtl option but i can't use it everywhere (if it's gonna be enough tell me! ). my solution was different component in ltr / rtl folders so check my language direction and import the correct one. and that's where i'm stuck!! i'm storing lang and dir in vuex and don't have access to them outside of export default{} ( i should check the direction right above it when importing components ). i know i'm missing some easy solution so i really appreciate your helps!!

Comment: after thinking a lot i only got one solution. cookie!!